# How to run HTTP server, UDP Server and WebSocket Server from a single NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, rxjs

As NodeJS is single threaded runtime platform, how to run the following servers in parallel from within single NodeJS app:

1. NodeJS's http server: to serve HTML5 app
2. A WebSocket server: to serve WebSocket connection to HTML5 app using same http connection opened at http server.
3. UDP server: to expose service discovery endpoint for other independently running NodeJS apps on same machine or on other machines/docker containers.

I was thinking about somehow achieving the above by using RxJS, but would rather want to listen to the community about their solution/experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is not single threaded. The developer only has access to a thread. But under the hoods, node.js is multi-threaded.

Specifically for your question, You can start multiple servers in the same process. [Socket.io getting started example](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) shows running websockets with http server. Same thing can also be done with UDP.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can have as many listening servers as you want in your node.js process.  As long as you write proper asynchronous code in your handlers and don't have any CPU-hogging algorithms to run, you should be just fine.

Second, your webSocket and http server can be the exact same server process as that's how webSocket was designed to work.

Your UDP listener then just needs to be on some different port from your web server.

The single-threaded aspect of node.js applies only to your Javascript.  You can run multiple server listeners just fine.  If two requests on different servers come in at the same time, the one that arrives slightly before the other will get its handler called and the one arrive just a bit later will be queued until the handler for the first is done or returns while waiting for an asynchronous operation itself.  In this way, the single threaded node.js can handle many requests.